# How to transpose a matrix into a second column, while the first column being the first element

Tags: r, matrix, vector

First of all I've never coded anything in my life, and I'm just learning R this week.
I'm not sure if the title is any clear, but I guess showing my problem is easier:
Let's say I have this Matrix (m):

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    A    1    2    3
 [2,]    B    1    4
 [3,]    C    3
```

Basically that A contains 1, 2 and 3, B contains 1 and 4 and so on.
How would I show that in a matrix with 2 columns only?

```
        [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    A    1
 [2,]    A    2
 [3,]    A    3
 [4,]    B    1
 [5,]    B    4
 [6,]    C    3
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have NA elements

Comment: Your original `m` matrix is rather unclear. You have both character and numeric data stored in there, which means it is probably all character now (matrices only support one type of data at a time). Can you provide `dput(m)` (just type it in R and hit enter, then copy and paste the results) as well so we can figure out exactly the structure you have?

Comment: I just used those as an exemple. The data, both for the character and numeric, is something like this: 004-496-068-664-557, which I cannot split it and it turns out as a character, but that's not a problem, I think. Anyway, here is the results: structure(c("004-496-068-664-557", (...) .Dim = c(19L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Lens.ID", "X", "X.1", "X.2", "X.3", "X.4", 
    "X.5", "X.6", "X.7", "X.8", "X.9"))). The (...) is me shortening a bunch of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the blanks showed are `NA`, get the count of NA elements per row with `rowSums`, `cbind` the `rep`licated first column based on 'n' while `t`ransposing the rest of the columns after omitting the `NA`s

```
n <- rowSums(!is.na(m1[,-1]))
cbind(rep(m1[,1], n), na.omit(c(t(m1[,-1]))))
#   [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "A"  "1" 
#[2,] "A"  "2" 
#[3,] "A"  "3" 
#[4,] "B"  "1" 
#[5,] "B"  "4" 
#[6,] "C"  "3"
```

---

Or a slightly more compact option is to replicate the first column with `col` index, `cbind` with the `t`ranspose of rest of the columns, and finally remove the NA rows with `na.omit`

```
na.omit(cbind(m1[,1][col(m1[,-1])], c(t(m1[,-1]))))
#   [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "A"  "1" 
#[2,] "A"  "2" 
#[3,] "A"  "3" 
#[4,] "B"  "1" 
#[5,] "B"  "4" 
#[6,] "C"  "3"
```

NOTE: `matrix` cannot have multiple column types.  So, if there is a character class, all the elements are converted to `character`

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c("A", "B", "C", "1", "1", "3", "2", "4", NA, "3", 
NA, NA), .Dim = 3:4)
```